# Can I use とおり (toori) for similes?

Tags: grammar

I know とおり (toori) means "as per", to convey accordance, like, 計画{けいかく}どおり (keikaku doori) = according to plan. But I wanna know whether it can also be used for sentences like this, or whether I should instead only use ように (you ni):

> 怖い猫どおり/のとおりにおそいかけた。
> kowai neko doori/no toori ni osoikaketa.
> Attacked like a frightened cat.

or

> 怖い猫のようにおそいかけた。
> kowai neko no you ni osoikaketa.

Comment: I wonder if you meant to type "osoikaketa".

Comment: That's what I wrote. Am I missing something? Oh I guess my question got edited.

Comment: Might just be my lack of knowledge, but I thought it should be osoika**ka**ta. I don't see osoika**ke**ru in the dictionaries I checked.

Comment: I found osoikakeru on an online dictionary. I don't rely on physical dictionaries. Also, some dictionaries, even online, lack certain words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to goo辞書 : [通り](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A_%28%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A%29/)

> ６ 同じ状態・方法であること。「予想した通りの成果が出た」「私の言った通りだ」「今までの通りに行う」

However, I think 怖{こわ}い猫{ねこ}どおり/のとおりにおそいかけた。: "Attacked like a frightened cat." does not follow the definition in the dictionary since 怖い猫 is more of the state: 状態 than the method/manner: 方法.

I do not think cats have plans/methods to be in a bad/nervous mood and they do not want to be in the mood for a while since some time ago. Rather something bad/unexpected having happened to the cat, hence they have happened to be in bad mood.

Also, it does not match to the example sentence in the dictionary 「予想した通りの成果が出た」 : "the same outcome as what you have expected", 「今までの通りに行う」: "the same way as the previous way".

Thus, ~のように is more appropriate to the "Similes" than ~のとおり.

Lastly, semantically speaking in your sentence,  怖い猫: "a frightened cat" is very awkward since 怖い is "scared","frightened" and so on, so the agent is more passive than active. Now they are going to attack, so it is more active than passive. 怒った : "getting angry", 警戒{けいかい}していた: "being alarmed" or something like which is more reactive to the situation should be chosen.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and clarification on passivity vs activity.

The only reason I'm dissatisfied with the answer regarding 'toori' is that you're attempting to answer it using the dictionary definition, whereas I often come by different interpretations of Japanese grammar. It leaves the door open for something to say "I heard it once used like that" to confirm my answer.

I need to be sure since I'm writing all these down in an orderly manner on my note book.

Comment: @Daniel Abraham Hmm,I don't get what you mean though, 怖い猫どおり/のとおりに is very awkward at first. 通り normally means path/way/road/etc. , which is difficult to connect the temporal emotion of cats. So, 怒った猫のように~ seems more natural simile.

Comment: Okay then. I'll trust your discretion. Thank you :D

Comment: I am also confused by the explanation (though I agree that のように is a much more applicable phrase in general). You say that the example doesn't follow the definition in the dictionary since 怖い猫 is "more the state: 状態 than the method/manner: 方法" - yet in the specific dictionary definition you cited, it *explicitly* says that the expression can refer to having the same 状態 *or* 方法. While I don't doubt your conclusion, I feel your rationale could be much clearer than it currently is.

Comment: @Micah Cowan Thanks for the reviewing and feedback. Yeah, I think I wanted to say it is awkward to regard 怖い猫/怒った猫 as 同じ状態/同じ方法, but 怖い猫/怒った猫 is simply the state cats show at some moments. Because, cats does not have any routine/scenario to be angry/frightened state on their own (i.e it is difficult to imagine cats prefer to have their tail be pulled for getting angry/nervous). So, 怖い猫 refers more of the state at single moment than the state repeating/recurring.